# How do I convert a list of numbers into their corresponding chr()

Tags: python, list, chr

```
c = list(range(97, 121))
```

If I print this it will give

```
[97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119]
```

Each of these number's `chr()` is string(alphabet) but how do I convert this list to the alphabet when I print `c`

```
c = list(range(chr(97),chr(121)))
```

It gives an error. So not really sure, how to convert them all at once rather than doing them individually.

Comment: Is it python code ? You If so you should tag is python.

Comment: sorry my bad yeah python

Comment: then **you** should add the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hivert's solution is really good if you want to convert a range of numbers into characters, but if you have a pre-existing list of integers that you want to convert into characters, you could adapt the solution like this:

```
intList = [97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106]
charList = [chr( intList[i] ) for i in range( 0, len( intList ) )]
```

Comment: why use an index when you can just iterate the list directly?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a list comprehension

```
c = [chr(i) for i in range(97, 121)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
intlist = [97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106]

charlist = [chr(x) for x in intlist]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
intList = [97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106]
charList = [chr(c) for c in intList]
string = "".join(charList)
```

Comment: Apart from that last (unnecessary) operation, this is the same as an earlier solution.